# fire pan/zoom events only when inside a defined g

Tags: svgpanzoom

Basically i'd like to fire pan/zoom events only when mouse\pinch occour on a specified group.

PS: the layer demo allow transformation on a group but panning-zooming events still propagate from the svg tag

Comment: well i've solved adding some option to the lib.
when it's stable and fixed i'll make a pull request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature was added in version 3.2.5.